# Привет. Скажите мне неучу, как мне через Iframe (или по другому) вывести на сайт видео ИМЕННО с компьютера, НЕ с youtube или с другого сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css

`<iframe src="...." frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Comment: В сторону WebRTC нужно смотреть для вывода видео с компьютера

Comment: На какой сайт и с какого компьютера?

Comment: на свой сайт, обычное видео из документов(с диска ssd или hhd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в целом для видео используется тег

```
<video src='здесь ссылка на сам файл'></video>
```

далее зависит от ряда условий.

видео сохранённое на вашем пк локально(hdd\ssd) нужно отобразить на той странице которую **будете просматривать только вы**?
достаточно указать локальный путь:

file:///C:/myVideos/movie.mp4

видео должно быть доступным к просмотру и остальным? загружайте его на свой хост\VPS\youtube\облако и линкуйте(не все облака позволяют смотреть файлы загруженные к ним без открытия страницы предпросмотра).

нужна трансляция? для создания потока гляньте в сторону VLC media player например, ну или поприставайте к стримерам с расспросами, что они юзают для этого.

Comment: OBS для выпуливания трансляций в сеть, но нужен принимающий сервер (RTMP протокол)